# How to make my custom theme suggestion the most specific

Tags: theming, 8

Is it possible to guarantee my custom theme suggestion is at the top of the list for theme suggestions? Something like the following

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
  x my-custom-theme-suggestion.html.twig
  x input--textfield.html.twig  // ALSO WHY DO I HAVE TWO OF THESE
  x input--textfield.html.twig
  * input.html.twig
-->
```

Also I'm not sure why but I have two theme suggestions that are the same. Anyone else experience that?

Comment: This seems to be a core issue, [Incorrect order and duplicate theme hook suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/2752443). Comment [#37](https://www.drupal.org/node/2752443#comment-12036332) links off to a potential solution for the core issue, [Convert theme hooks (defined by hook_theme()) to be objects](https://www.drupal.org/node/2863819).

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions is a PHP array that is provided by a hook and an alter hook. The standard rules apply, alter hook is later, so add it there to be more likely to be the last.

And if you want to be sure, set the module weight and/or implements hook_module_implements_alter() to ensure that your module is the one that is called last.

If you want to implement this in a theme then you only use the alter hook anyway and the module_implements_alter() won't work, but themes and especially the active themes are called last anyway.

The duplicate is possibly because the defaults include a suggestion for the field type and one for the field name, so if you name it the same as the field type, then you get the same suggestion twice

Comment: Yes, this is the way it should work but it currently is not. I have added a comment to my post explaining why.